# How do you line up variable width text entities in I-Frame?

Tags: wordpress, text, aframe

How do you line up variable width text entities in I-Frame?

I'm trying to develop an I-Frame WordPress template but I'm running into newbe issues that I just can't seem to figure out. I am using a loop to spit out menu items into aframe-text-component entities but I want them to line up automatically without having to edit each items position. The problem is the widths. Is there any way I can measure the widths of the items as they come down and then sit them next to each other with a predetermined amount of space in between each item set?

Or use I-Frame's API to cycle through each item and position them on page load?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>MyPage</title>
        <script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/aframe.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://rawgit.com/ngokevin/aframe-text-component/master/dist/aframe-text-component.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a-scene>
            <? $my_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items('Menu 1');
            foreach ($my_menu as $key => $menu_item) { ?>
                <a-entity id='menu_i_<? echo $key; ?>' material="color: #FFC65D" position="0 3.25 -4" text="text: <? echo $menu_item->title; ?>" url='<? echo $menu_item->url; ?>'></a-entity>              
            <? } ?>
        </a-scene>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [bmfont-text component](https://github.com/bryik/aframe-bmfont-text-component) which is more performant, prettier, and automatically aligns.

But you could also try using the bounding box and offsetting the text.

```
var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(textEl.getObject3D('mesh'));
textEl.setAttribute('position', {
  x: (bbox.max.x - bbox.min.x) / 2,
  y: textEl.object3D.position.y,
  z: textEl.object3D.position.z
});
```

Comment: Thanks ngokevin but I'm getting a weird "e.updateMatrixWorld is not a function" error. 

I like bmfont-text component but I have to use separate elements for interactive purposes so even with that I'm in the same boat. Unless you know how to sit the elements next to each other but still be separate elements. I looked throughout their pages and can't find how to do that.

Comment: When you call that code, make sure the mesh is initialize. Either stick that code in a component that has `dependencies: ['text']` or use `loaded` event listener.